# CMake: variables generated by add_library()?

Tags: cmake

I am resurrecting a 10-year-old C++ project that has a top level CMakeLists.txt file which sets the BUILD_TYPE_SDK variable to either STATIC or SHARED, and a the library level CMakeLists.txt that has the line:

```
    ADD_LIBRARY(foo ${BUILD_TYPE_SDK} ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})
```

and I have a C++ header file [reformatted for clarity] which is testing for:

```
    #ifdef foo_EXPORTS
    #      define FOO_DLL_DEF __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #   ifdef foo_STATIC
    #      define FOO_DLL_DEF
    #   else
    #      define FOO_DLL_DEF __declspec(dllimport)
    #   endif
    #endif
```

and it all seems to work, but nowhere can I find where foo_EXPORTS is declared or defined.

Is foo_EXPORTS a variable that is created as a side-effect of the ADD_LIBRARY() call? If so, where can I find a list of other generated variables?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, that `foo_EXPORTS` define gets added by CMake when building `foo` target. This way it is set to `export` when you are building the library and to `import` when you are using it from within another target.

There is a special [CMake module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) that makes it easy to generate such headers.

Comment: As far as I can see, I'm not explicitly calling GenerateExportHeader as described in the link, but it looks like something similar could be being called implicitly to generate and/or #define foo_EXPORTS behind the scenes. Thanks for the information.